# No puedo alinear horizontalmente mi header

Tags: html, scss

**No puedo alinear horizontalmente mi header**

este es el código HTML:

```
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="logo">
      <nav class="">
        <ul class="navLinks">
          <li><a href="./pages/information.html">Conocenos</a></li>
          <li><a href="./pages/clients.html">Clientes</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="./pages/contact.html" class="btn"><button>Contacto</button></a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

y pasamos al SCSS

```
.header{
    background-color: $firstColor;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    padding: 5px, 10%;
    .logo{
        margin-right: auto ;
        cursor: pointer;
        img {
            height: 70px;
            width: auto;
            transition: all 0.3s; 
            padding: 15px 20px;      
        }
        img:hover{
            transform: scale(1.2);
        }
    }         
    .navLinks {
        list-style: none;

    }
    li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }
    li:hover{
        transform: scale(1.2);   
    }
    a{
        font-size: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: beige;
    }
    a:hover{
        color: $hoverColor;
    }

    .btn{
        button{
            font-weight: 700;
            color: $firstColor;
            padding: 9px 25px;
            background-color: $secondaryColor;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
```

por lo que me queda el logo alineado en el header pero luego los link por fuera y uno debajo del otro.
lo que quiero es que quede el logo a la izquierda, luego los links alienados a la derecha pero todo a la vez alineado horizontalmente dentro del header
Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda que me brinden!!

Answer (score 0):

Para alinear horizontalmente el logo y los enlaces dentro del encabezado (header), puedes utilizar la propiedad `display: flex` en la clase `.logo` y en la clase `.navLinks`. Además, puedes utilizar la propiedad `justify-content: space-between` en la clase `.logo` para que el logo se alinee a la izquierda y los enlaces se alineen a la derecha.

Aquí está el código SCSS modificado:

```
.header {
  background-color: $firstColor;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  padding: 5px 10%;

  .logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;

    img {
      height: 70px;
      width: auto;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      padding: 15px 20px;
    }

    img:hover {
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
  }

  .navLinks {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
  }

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
  }

  li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  a {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: beige;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: $hoverColor;
  }

  .btn {
    button {
      font-weight: 700;
      color: $firstColor;
      padding: 9px 25px;
      background-color: $secondaryColor;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
  }
}
```